# Google Analytics - Is Session Time dependent on measured site to be in the current tab?

Tags: google-analytics, session

Suppose that I enter in a site and, 10 seconds later, I change for another tab that contains another site.  19 minutes and 50 seconds after, I return to the original tab and close that site. Which session time is measured? 20 minutes or 10 seconds?

I think that it would be fair consider just 10 seconds, that it's total time that I've spent in the site that is being measured by Google Analytics.

Answer (score 2):

GA would see the session time as 20 minutes because it doesn't know that you visited a different site on a different tab.

Comment: Thank you. I've read that tools like Clicky allow to measure the real time inside the site.